# Regular expression for double number range validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, numbers

I look for a regular expression to support double number with just one fraction part which ranges between 0.1 to 999.9

It means following values are not allowed:

```
0
0.0 // less than lower bound
0.19 // fraction part is 2 digits, right '9' is extra
94.11 // fraction part is 2 digits, right '1' is extra
999.90 // fraction part is 2 digits, '0' is extra
9.0 // should be 9 or 9.1, 9.0 is wrong
1000 // is higher than upper bound
```

allowed ones:

```
1.1
55.5
999.9
```

My regular expression is:

```
(^(\.[1-9])?$|(^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}?(\.[1-9])?$))$
```

Which doesn't support `0.1` to `0.9` and extra zeros like `99.000` and `99.0`

Test steps:
In your browser console:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/(^(\.[1-9])?$|(^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}?(\.[1-9])?$))$/);
reg.test(12);
```

Any help appriciated

Comment: `reg.test("12");` because you're testing strings, not numbers.

Comment: Do you want to test numbers or strings? Because it makes no difference in numbers how many zeros they have in the end of the fraction part. E.g. `12.1 === 12.1000`.

Comment: From reading the answers, there seems to be a lot of confusion around your requirements, @YasserMoradi.  Perhaps you could take a step back and explain what your goal is?

Comment: @MarkReed I've an validation engine that uses validations based on regular expressions and|or schematron, and tests data on both client side javaScript and server side(.NET), We are extending that, but for now, we should use this method.

Comment: I get that you may have to use regexes instead of arbitrary code to do the validation, but why do you have to be so specific about the form of the number?  Why is "9" OK but "9.0" bad, etc?

Comment: @MarkReed I'm agree with you, but I'm responsible for the framework and validation engine itself, The business analyzers and developers are doing on their own.

Comment: in case it helps someone, I created a javascript tool that creates a highly optimized regex from two inputs (min/max) https://github.com/jonschlinkert/to-regex-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the most accurate:

```
/^(0\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[1-9])?)$/
```

Note that you don't need the `RegExp` constructor when working with regex literals:

```
 re = /^(0\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[1-9])?)$/
 a = [0, 0.1, 123, 123.4, '00.1', 123.45, 123456, 'foo']
 a.map(function(x) { console.log(x, re.test(x)) })
```

---

```
0 false
0.1 true
123 true
123.4 true
00.1 false
123.45 false
123456 false
foo false
```

Comment: Very close to what we need, thank you. It doesn't support 1.80 >> false, but it's not important.

Comment: @YasserMoradi: it does return false when `1.80` is given as a _string_: `re.test("1.80")`. But the _numbers_ `1.8` and `1.80` are identical, so `re.test(1.80)` will be the same as `re.test(1.8)`.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake

Answer (score 3):

Following regex should for you:

```
^[1-9]([0-9]{1,2})?(\.[1-9])?$
```

Comment: `{1,2}?` can be simply `{0,2}`.

Comment: @thg435: Yes that's true and that is what Teneff has posted about 13 mins later :P

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would add an alternative way to accomplish this with [a node.js javascript library](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/to-regex-range) that I created for generating these ranges automatically.

To use the library, you would first need to install it using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/):

```
$ npm install --save to-regex-range
```

Then add the library to your application with the following line of code

```
var toRegexRange = require('to-regex-range');
```

The main export is a function that takes two integers: the `min` value and `max` value (formatted as strings or numbers).

**Examples**

```
console.log(toRegexRange('111', '555'));
//=> 11[1-9]|1[2-9][0-9]|[2-4][0-9]{2}|5[0-4][0-9]|55[0-5]

console.log(toRegexRange('5', '5'));
//=> 5

console.log(toRegexRange('5', '6'));
//=> [5-6]

console.log(toRegexRange('51', '229'));
//=> 5[1-9]|[6-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-2][0-9]

console.log(toRegexRange('29', '51'));
//=> 29|[3-4][0-9]|5[0-1]

console.log(toRegexRange('1', '100000'));
//=> [1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,4}|100000
```

The [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-regex-range) has more documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^\d{1,3}\.[1-9]$/);
```

It works with all the positive and negative cases you supplied.

Comment: fractional part should be optional.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but was not complete, I try to improve that. Thanks

Comment: @Mark Reed, I agree with you in the general case but it really depends what the asker is trying to do. I'm trying not to second-guess his requirements.

Comment: I wasn't stating a personal belief, @acfrancis. Based on the post, integers with no fractional part ("9") are allowed, while integral values with a spurious decimal attached ("9.0") are not. See 6th example in the "incorrect" list, with associated comments.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. Reading the whole thing again, the requirements still seem odd to me. "9.0" is a good decimal number where I come from. That's a joke, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex at all. Some simple (and much faster than regex) math equeations will do the job:

```
function testNumber(number) {
    if (number < 0.1 || number > 999.9 || parseInt(10*number) != 10*number || number == parseInt(number))
        return false;

    return true;
}

alert( testNumber(12) );
```

In the `if` statement we check 4 things:

- is the number lower than 0.1
- is the number higher than 999.9
- does the number have more than one digit in thefraction part
- is the number an integer (no digits in fraction part)

If **any** of the conditions above is *true* then te function returns *false*.

Comment: But `number == parseInt(number)` eliminates all integral values.  Those aren't disallowed, they just need to not have a .0 tacked on.  If I'm reading OP's rules right, anyway. The point is, there are restrictions on the form of the number that seem to go beyond its value and that it is a legal float.

Comment: @MarkReed, I don't think so. Look at the 6th example in OP's __disallowed__ numbers (9.0).

Comment: Yes.  But per OP, "12.1" is allowed, and "12.10000" is not.

Comment: Right. The string "9.0" is disallowed.  Look at comment: "should be 9"

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. Now I am totally confused. The OP wants to check numbers but he doesn't assume that leading zeros doesn't matter in numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I've to use regular expression because of limitations of our validation engine.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off first checking if the number is a double using Regex and then checking separately if it falls inside the range. Having business logic obfuscated by something like Regex means your code is harder to maintain. And if you ever have to update your business logic to other numbers, you'll have a hard time.

```
[-+]?([0-9]*\.[1-9]|[0-9]+)
```

the above Regex validates a floating point. After that, you can just ParseFloat and compare for the rest of the logic.

Comment: @YasserMoradi Are you sure? I used http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html to verify it, and the above regex gives a match for 1.11

Comment: And I just realized that you want 1 decimal at most. give me a moment to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

While you shouldn't use Regexp to compare ranges of numbers, here is one that should work for your case:

```
/^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.[1-9])?)|(?:0\.[1-9])$/
```

Example (unanchored): http://regex101.com/r/dY5pL3

Comment: Thanks, but it fails in several tests

Comment: Sorry, i had forgotten to anchor the regex (check the edited version). Let me know what tests it fails please, i couldn't find any.